# What is Lazy Minting in Ethereum?

Tags: ether, gas, gas-price, nft, mint

I am trying to create NFTs in various digital/crypto marketplaces like OpenSea, Rarible, etc for the past few weeks. In most of the sites, we need to pay some gas fees for adding an asset and creating an NFT for it. But OpenSea doesn't ask for any gas fees for adding an asset in Ethereum. After adding the asset I could see the contract address and unique Token ID for it. But how it is possible to deploy a contract and create an NFT with zero gas fee? On their official website, they have mentioned that they use "Lazy Minting" which is, the NFT token is really minted on the blockchain while its first purchase or transfer.

> The new collection manager allows creators to make NFTs without any upfront gas cost, as the NFT isn’t transferred on-chain until the first purchase or transfer is made. We call this lazy minting. It unbundles the on-chain issuance of your NFTs from the metadata.

But technically I couldn't understand the concept behind this. Do they use any await function and promise to achieve this? Or is there any other alternative way?

For more info, Please find the contract address and Token Id for the asset I have added,

> Contract address: 0x495f947276749Ce646f68AC8c248420045cb7b5e

> Token ID: 34933046909214840971720565469667075475484107771494388163319263788272235577345

Comment: Write the contract address and the token id please in the question

Comment: Now I have included both in the question:)

Comment: okay it is a shared contract and the owner of the contract didn't published his code, how do you that the TokenId is in the contract ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried to find the token details in Etherscan Token Tracker but I couldn't
see any details

Comment: I think they have published the contract for the Rinkeby network transactions, So I tried to find the token details of both newly created and purchased assets, it is showing my wallet address as owner of the asset in both cases.

In case if you want to check please use this,
Contract address (Rinkeby): 0xeE45B41D1aC24E9a620169994DEb22739F64f231
Newly added asset Token: 34933046909214840971720565469667075475484107771494388163319263789371747205121
Purchased asset Token: 34933046909214840971720565469667075475484107771494388163319263787172723949569

Comment: @Sandhiya Without any evidence it seems minting is done off-chain. When someone purchases the token on their marketplace then it is minted on-chain by an authorized operator.

Comment: @Ismael Oh okay. Could please explain more about what is minting on Off-chain? Does it mean they use some other method to calculate the token id and later mint on-chain while purchasing?

Comment: @Sandhiya I'm just guessing I know nothing about OpenSea implementation. For similar functionality I'd use a regular database to store tokens ids and other details. For blockchain stuff a layer 2 solution might seem more appropriate.

Comment: @Ismael Oh got it. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://blog.openzeppelin.com/workshop-recap-building-an-nft-merkle-drop/

Lazy minting uses cryptographic primitives, the artist can sign “minting authorizations” that later allow a user to do the minting themselves. These signatures are free to produce, as they do not require an on-chain transaction. They guarantee that the artist or system administrator keeps total control over the NFTs, and ensure no token can be minted without prior approval.